# Getting option label via $emit

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

I'm using vue-select as my dropdown. Vue-select has a prop called getOptionLabel to return a property from an object. I have a component where I pass a method to to get the code from the option object and I emit the method from my created component but the label is not showing. Please help me.

This what I've tried:

```
<dropdown-items
    name="item"
    :labelElement="$t('fields.item')"
    :keyElement="'item-field'"
    :item_id="itemReceiveItem.item_id"
    :options="items"
    @setOptionLabel="updateItemLabel"
    @selectItem="
        (event) =>
            updateItem({
                key: itemReceiveItem.id,
                item_id: event.id,
                attr: 'item_id',
            })
    "
    @clearSelected="
        clearSelectedItem({
            key: itemReceiveItem.id,
            item_id: itemReceiveItem.item_id,
            attr: 'item_id',
        })
    "
    @activeField="activeField"
/> 

updateItemLabel(option) {
    if (typeof option === 'object') return option.code;

    const optionObject = this.lists.items.find(
        (item) => item.id.toString() === option.toString()
    );

    if (optionObject) return optionObject.code;

    return option;
},
```

**DropdownItem.vue**

```
<v-select
    :name="name"
    :key="keyElement"
    :value="item_id"
    :options="options"
    :clearable="false"
    :get-option-label="onSetOptionLabel"
    :disabled="item_id ? true : false"
    @input="onSelectItem($event)"
/>

<script>
export default {
  emits: ['selectItem', 'clearSelected', 'setOptionLabel'],
  methods: {
    onSetOptionLabel(option) {
      this.$emit('setOptionLabel', option);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Walking through your code, `:get-option-label` calls the method `onSetOptionLabel()`.  This method emits an event containing the `option` value.
Your parent component captures the event and calls `updateItemLabel` method passing in that same `option` value.  This parent method performs some logic and returns a value... ***where is the value returned?*** It's not to the v-select, that's down in the child component.  The answer is nowhere.

There are a few ways you could solve your problem but in my opinion you should pass down `this.lists.items` to **DropdownItem.vue** as an additional prop and perform all the necessary label logic within that component to keep things as simple as possible.  Whatever method you assign to `get-option-label`, *that's* the method that needs to return a value for the labels to be set.  So put all necessary logic in that `onSetOptionLabel` method and remove the emit.